# Issues making Python modules to work inside Ubuntu environment at PyCharm

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I am having issues with properly installing Tkinter and PyQt5 in my Ubuntu environment (I have a Windows computer with Ubuntu activated and linked to PyCharm).

I have tried installing via the packages installer inside PyCharm and via codes in the Ubuntu terminal itself (like *apt-get install* and *pip install*). Even though some installations seemed to work, the modules are not being loaded properly. In fact, Tkinter doesn't even show up as a download option inside PyCharm (I only found "tk" but it doesn't seem to work the same).

After trying a bunch of stuff, these are the messages I get when trying to load these packages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part3_displaying_table.py", line 18, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: bad magic number in 'PyQt5': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part2_visualizing_venn.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Any ideas of what might be happening?

**P.S. 1:** I have the exact same repositories installed in my Windows OS and importing the modules/running the code work completely fine.

**P.S. 2:** I need to install those in the Linux environment because I will need to call a program in my code that is not compatible with Windows; as a consequence I will have to run the whole code in my Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter:

Step 2 - can Tkinter be imported?

Try the correct command for your version at the Python prompt:

```
>>> import Tkinter # no underscore, uppercase 'T' for versions prior to V3.0
>>> import tkinter # no underscore, lowercase 't' for V3.0 and later
```

If it works, go to step 3.

If it fails with "No module named Tkinter", your Python configuration needs to be changed to include the directory that contains `Tkinter.py` in its default module search path. You have probably forgotten to define `TKPATH` in the `Modules/Setup` file. A temporary workaround would be to find that directory and add it to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It is the subdirectory named `lib-tk` of the Python library directory (when using Python 1.4 or before, it is named `tkinter`).